# How to Add class in Magento 2 checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, page

I want to add class in magento 2 checkout page for designing.
Is it Possible to do.?

Thanks.

If I add a class in New Address button like below code in shipping.html file.

```
<button type="button"
            data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
            class="action action-show-popup primary s2">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
        <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Where you have  to add class in checkout? and you are using one step checkout ?

Comment: In shipping address fields and all fields and progress bars also

Comment: Which place you want to add class, in shipping.html file?

Comment: I am adding class in button tag class name="primary s2"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check in Magento Checkout module. You can check in `app\design\frontend\your-package\themename\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart`. If module doesn't exist in theme copy required files from `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates` to `app\design\frontend\your-package\themename\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\` and add class there in phtml file.

**OR**

you can add classes in html file by copy files from `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\` to `app\design\frontend\your-package\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template`.

After making any change in html file. You can run commands in this sequence:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo chmod -R 777 pub
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo chmod -R 777 pub
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
```

also clear browser cache.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is in theme folder but when adding classes it will not take

Comment: You deployed static content after change, sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: No i just compile using sudo php/bin magento setup:di:compile

Comment: After making any change you need to run cache clear & static content deploy commands.

Comment: Yes I all do...

Comment: Okay then please share in which file you have to add class?

Comment: if I add class in shipping.html file in New address button

Answer (score 0):

Copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

and add to below file path

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

Now you can add button class in this file.

Let me know if you have any query from this.

Run below commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Hello @S H Patel I am also do above method but can not get output

Comment: Check file path is correct or not. I have checked and tested code, works for me.

Comment: Yes i am checking all paths